# Find angle of rectangle from MSER

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision

I have implemented an MSER detector in C# after reading several papers scattered out on the web and have achieved a desired output (Lots of interesting and fun stuff to me! :) )

[image: Input Image]
Fig 1 - Input Image
[image: Output Image]
Fig 2 - Output Image
[image: Ellipse Fit]
Fig 3 - Best fit ellipse

If you zoom in on Fig. 2, you would see one red pixel which is the calculated centroid of the region from the image moments. Google found me a best fit ellipse algorithm that works very well, as see in Fig. 3.

The problem:

> I need to find the orientation of the MSER preferably in degrees from a common reference point. The ellipse provides some of this data; however, as you can see in Fig 3. sometimes the ellipse fit isn't properly orientated whereas the region as seen in Fig. 2. very obviously has an angle off zero (zero being if you laid a standard unit circle over the image -- straight right from center).

The motivation

> As I stated earlier this is fun to me and really peaks my interest. I just finished building a homemade pick and place and am planning on doing some vision experiments of my own later down the line for both personal and academic gain. I do have intent to release all my code under a do-whatever-you-want-with-it open source license once I get all my credits and documentation in order!

The question

> Can anyone point me in the direction of an algorithm I could implement that would turn an *unsorted* list of X,Y points into a reduced area rectangle I could use to get orientation, size and location data from? Any help appreciated!

Sorry for the length, wanted to be clear!

Currently working in C#; however, examples in Java,C,C++ are acceptable and preferred, other languages welcome.

Comment: Some of those best-fit ellipses are already tilted, so it seems that the algorithm is capable of tilting them to increase fit.  So I would first check that there isn't a bug in that algorithm.  E.g. the top-left and top-right ellipses look particularly bad -- I would see if you can manually find an ellipse that has strictly better score according to whatever scoring function is used to choose the "optimal" ellipse.

Comment: In any case, linear regression should work fine for rectangular-shaped objects.  The longer and skinnier the blobs are, the better.